# Why does team foundation displays "+" for folders with no subfolders

Tags: version-control, tfs

What is weird is that, Team Foundation source control displays "+" for folders with no subfolders.

[image]

it becomes apparent when you click on the bin folder.

[image]

**Why does team foundation source control displays "+" folers with no subfolders?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a performance optimisation so that the view doesn't have to enumerate the folder contents in order to decide whether it should draw a + or not.

This pattern is often followed by programs which offer a view of hierarchical data on remote systems where the performance penalty for listing a node's contents can be large.